# Misaligned bins in matplotlib stackplot

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to make a stack plot where the bins don't seem to be aligning correctly with the data. What I have plotted is the proportion of something in a sphere as you go radially outward from the center. The error became visible to me in the rightmost section of this plot. The lighter blue should be a vertical column of one width. Instead the dark blue seems to slant into the lighter blue section.

What I believe is the problem is that the data are not evenly spaced. For example: at a radius of 300 I might have a certain proportion value. Then at a radius of 330 I might have another, then the next at 400. 
[image]

I had thought that stackplot would be able to take care of this but it appears not. Is there a way for me to straighten up these columns of data?

Source Code:

```
def phaseProp(rad,phase):

#phaseLabel = np.array(['coe','en','fs','olv','maj','perov','ppv','ring','wad','per','wust','st'])
#print phaseLabel
rad = rad/1000.
phase = phase/100.
print phase[:,:]
#print phase[:,0]
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (15,10))
ax.stackplot(rad[:],phase[:,0],phase[:,1],phase[:,2],phase[:,3],phase[:,4],   \
               phase[:,5],phase[:,6],phase[:,7],phase[:,8],                   \
               phase[:,9] ,phase[:,10],phase[:,11],phase[:,12],                           \
               colors = ['gainsboro','gold','lightsage','darkorange','tomato','indianred',\
                       'darksage','sage','palevioletred','darkgrey','dodgerblue' ,'mediumblue' ,'darkblue' ])        

plt.legend([mpatches.Patch(color='gainsboro'),  
            mpatches.Patch(color='gold'), 
            mpatches.Patch(color='lightsage'),
            mpatches.Patch(color='darkorange'),
            mpatches.Patch(color='tomato'),
            mpatches.Patch(color='indianred'),
            mpatches.Patch(color='darksage'),
            mpatches.Patch(color='sage'),
            mpatches.Patch(color='palevioletred'),
            mpatches.Patch(color='darkgrey'),
            mpatches.Patch(color='dodgerblue'),
            mpatches.Patch(color='mediumblue'),
            mpatches.Patch(color='darkblue')],

            ['coe','opx','ol','gt','pv','ppv','rw','wad','fp','st','h2o','iceIh','iceVII'],\
            loc='upper center', bbox_to_anchor=(0.5, 1.127),fancybox=True, shadow=True, ncol=5,fontsize='20')

plt.ylabel(r'Phase Proportion',fontsize = 34)
plt.xlabel(r'Radius (km)',fontsize = 34)
plt.tick_params(axis='both', which='both', labelsize=32)

plt.xlim(rad[noc+1],rad[nr])
plt.ylim(0,1.0)
#ax.stackplot(rad,phase)
#plt.gca().invert_xaxis()
plt.show()
```

Comment: could you please share the portion of you code that deals with this, and if possible the raw data too.

Comment: added some code. The data is just a 350 x 13 numpy array. The 13 'columns' range in value from 0 to 100. As you can see I normalized this to 1. I have been using this plot for awhile now and only noticed the error with the addition of the rightmost portion. The last 50 rows of the phase array should  be all 0s and one column of 1. Therefore they should display as vertical columns. They clearly dont. Thanks for taking the time to help.

Answer (score 0):

I've had a look at your problem and I think the problem lies with the fact that the last two points for the H20 line are (7100,0) and (7150,1) therefore it simply slopes up as you are seeing.

However it is very simple to add an additional point to give a square edge:

```
rad_amended = np.hstack((rad,rad[-1])) #extend the array by 1
rad_amended[-2] = rad[-2] +1 #alter the penultimate value
phase_amended = np.vstack((phase,phase[-1])) #extend the Y values
nr+=1 #extend the range of the x-axis
phaseProp(rad_amended,phase_amended)
```

This principle could be extended for the full dataset and give square edges to every Area, but I assume you are happy with the rest of the graph?

Comment: Thank you. I now see how stackplot works. The subsequent values are connected to one another linearly. Unfortunately, this isn't really what I want. I need each bin to be independent of one another. Is there an argument in stackplot to possibly delineate the data?

Comment: You could do that @handroski , as I said in my answer. But you'd end up with a stacked bar graph, albeit with bars of variable width. Would that be acceptable?

Comment: Oh right didn't see you mentioned that. I think the graph would smooth out and not look as crude as a histogram normally would. Though, I'm unsure until seeing it. I'm looking at using a stacked histogram and just passing a list of the widths in for the bin size. I'm assuming this is possible.

Comment: Your example was a little confusing for me which is why I was suggesting the idea above as a solution.

Comment: No worries, let me know how you get on with the histogram.  I've not checked but yes you probably can have variable widths, which would be much better than extending my suggestion above. It really comes down to how best to visualise your data, then a solution can easily be found.  Let us know how you get on.